# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} { \frac{(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+e^x}} }$ uniformly converge in $(-\infty, \infty)$?

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

> Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} { \frac{(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+e^x}}   }$ uniformly converge in $(-\infty, \infty)$?

As to now, what I did is say that $f_n(x) = \text {our sum}$ and say that it is $\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2 + e^x}} = g(x)$. Now I've been trying to prove that $g(x)$ converges but haven't been able to do so, I have tried the Ratio test, but it is inconclusive because $x$ can also be $\infty$.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: One thing though: $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2}} = \frac{1}{n^{2/3}}$

Comment: @DavidMitra : i guess there is a typo on your hint. W-M test doesn't seem to help in this case .

Comment: Too early for me ...

Comment: Let $b_i$ be the absolute value of the  $i$'th term of your series. Write the series as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} a_n$, where $a_1=b_1$, $a_2=b_2+b_3$, $a_3=b_4+b_5$, $\ldots\,$. Note $(a_i)_{1>1}$ is a decreasing, positive  sequence that converges uniformly to the zero function.  From this, you can show the series is uniformly Cauchy, thus uniformly convergent.